# Materialized view on a foreign table with postgresql_fdw

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views, foreign-data-wrapper

Is it possible to use a materialized view on top of a foreign table with postgresql_fdw? (Postgres 9.3)

Currently thinking of some kind of "caching" for postgresql_fdw.

Comment: As you can do a `select` on a foreign table and a MVIEW does only that, I can't see a reason why that shouldn't be possible.

Comment: I missed the REFRESH-part. Understood it will be updated via TRIGGER .... but needs to done "manual". My fault. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View can be updated by `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW`. No real need for external triggering.